# PHP Thruway + Authobahn.js = 426, how to use websockets with pub/sub?

Tags: php, websocket, autobahn, wamp-protocol, thruway

I'm trying to use websockets mainly for pushing data from server to client on events.

So, i configured locally [Thruway](https://github.com/voryx/ThruwayBundle) and [Autobahn.js](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js) twice: by myself and with help of [this tutorial](http://voryx.net/getting-started-with-the-thruwaybundle-for-symfony/).

Server starts correctly:

```
./bin/console thruway:router:start
Making a go at starting the Thruway Router
2018-05-23T00:29:33.6760270 debug      [Thruway\Peer\Router 17047] New router created
2018-05-23T00:29:33.6830490 info       [Thruway\Peer\Router 17047] Starting router
2018-05-23T00:29:33.6853010 info       [Thruway\Transport\RatchetTransportProvider 17047] Websocket listening on 127.0.0.1:9998
2018-05-23T00:29:33.6864550 info       [Thruway\Transport\RatchetTransportProvider 17047] Websocket listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
2018-05-23T00:29:33.6865040 info       [Thruway\Peer\Router 17047] Starting loop
```

Browser code is very simple:

```
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
    url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9999/',
    realm: 'realm1'
});
connection.onopen = function (session, details) {
    console.info('Connection opened: ' + session + ' | ' + details);
};
connection.onclose = function (reason, details) {
    console.info('Connection closed: ' + reason + ' | ' + details);
};
connection.open();
```

But i see error `426 No Sec-WebSocket-Protocols requested supported` in browsers (Safari, Chrome, FireFox).

After some googling, i found only very old questions/answers (2014..2016) where people says that Authobahn.js use WAMPv2 but Ratchet only WAMPv1.. but i see that WAMPv2 is supported by Thruway library in 2017-2018.

My question is simple: how to make this work? Or, maybe, with angularWAMP? Any examples are appreciated, thanks.

---

Versions:

```
~ composer show -D
sensio/distribution-bundle     v5.0.21  Base bundle for Symfony Distributions
sensio/framework-extra-bundle  v5.1.6   This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sensio/generator-bundle        v3.1.7   This bundle generates code for you
symfony/monolog-bundle         v3.2.0   Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge         v4.0.9   Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu          v1.8.0   Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle     v3.2.2   Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                v3.4.9   The Symfony PHP framework
thruway/pawl-transport         0.5.0    Pawl WebSocket Transport for Thruway Client
voryx/thruway-bundle           0.3.1    WebSockets (WAMP2) integration for Symfony2
```

Autobahn is 18.3.2

Comment: I have tried running your javascript code against the SimpleWsServer in Thruway and it works for me. Can you update with what version of Symfony, ThruwayBundle, and autobahn you are using?

Comment: @mbonneau sure, added

Comment: I tested an empty project and it still worked fine for me. I created a repo of the project so you can compare with yours: https://github.com/mbonneau/SE50478425 - The Javascript part is in testSE.html